# Java cryptography compile error

Tags: java, cryptography

I want to create PEM-encoded certification request but following code

shows error:

PKCS10CRexample.java:33: cannot find symbol

symbol  : variable Utils

location: class PKCS10CRexample

```
    kpGen.initialize(1024, Utils.createFixedRandom());
                           ^
```

1 error

but the code is example from'Beginning Cryptography with Java', thus it should not

include any syntax errors.

what is the problem?, what class should I include?

```
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;

import javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.PKCS10CertificationRequest;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMWriter;

public class PKCS10CRexample
{
    public static PKCS10CertificationRequest generateRequest(
            KeyPair pair)
            throws Exception

            {           
             return new PKCS10CertificationRequest(
                     "SHA256withRSA",
                     new X500Principal("CN=Requested Test Certificate"),
                     pair.getPublic(),
                     null,
                     pair.getPrivate());
            }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        //create the keys
        KeyPairGenerator kpGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");

        kpGen.initialize(1024, Utils.createFixedRandom());

        KeyPair pair=kpGen.generateKeyPair();

        PKCS10CertificationRequest request = generateRequest(pair);

        PEMWriter pemWrt = new PEMWriter(
                          new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));

        pemWrt.writeObject(request);

        pemWrt.close();


    }



}
```

Comment: You need to import your `Utils` class.

Comment: I know svz,, but I don't know which Utils class include createFixedRandom() method

Comment: Its not a syntax error. Your are missing a library. Please add appropriate jar to your class path.

Comment: thanks,, which jar should I have to add?

Comment: It's really hard to tell from here which one you need. Looks like it returns some random number. Try to replace it with a different `getRandom()` implementation.

Comment: The [Utils class](http://amadousarr.free.fr/java/JAVA-crypto-examples/doc/chapter4/Utils.html) which implements `createFixedRandom()`seems to be the one from Chapter 4 of the book.

Comment: @andih sounds like an answer to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Utils class](http://amadousarr.free.fr/java/JAVA-crypto-examples/doc/chapter4/Utils.html) which implements createFixedRandom()seems to be the one from Chapter 4 of the book.

Have a look at chapter 4 of the book and of the examples of this chapter.